# How to draw 2 different colored rectangles in iphone using 2d graphics

Tags: ipad, graphics, 2d

I have used the following code for drawing 2 rectangles

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();   
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(60,170,200,80);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextClosePath(context);

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGRect rectangle1= CGRectMake(60,170,500,80);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle1
                     );
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextClosePath(context);

}
```

But for the first rectangle I am able to fill it with red color, but the second one is not filling with color. only border appears with blue color.

Please suggest any way to do.